# Pages are merging for Reactjs routing?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have an issue while routing path of reactjs application.I need two exact paths

```
1.  path = /user/
2. path = /user/setting
```

When i call the second path its shows a merged page of both components

```
   <Route path='/user/:param1'   component={routeProps => <MyTab {...routeProps} remotes={remotes} />}/>
    <Route path='/(user/settings)/:param1'   component={UserSettings}/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write the routes wrapped by a switch component and reorder them so that the first matching route is rendered

```
<Switch>
    <Route path='/(user/settings)/:param1'   component={UserSettings}/>
    <Route path='/user/:param1'   component={routeProps => <MyTab {...routeProps} remotes={remotes} />}/>
</Switch>
```

The reason you see the current behaviour is because `'/(user/settings)/:param1'` also matches `'/user/:param1'` where `params`  will be `settings`  as we aren't checking for an exact match and hence both routes are rendered

Reordering the routes within Switch will make sure that if `/user/settings/:param1` matches the rest routes are not matched. If you do not re-order, the `'/user/:param1'` route will get matched for `/user/settings/:param1` and the UserSettings component will never be rendered

You could simply use exact keyword on both the routes like

```
<Route exact path='/user/:param1'   component={routeProps => <MyTab {...routeProps} remotes={remotes} />}/>
<Route exact path='/(user/settings)/:param1'   component={UserSettings}/>
```

However if you do that, you won't be able to write any nested routes within MyTab or UserSettings component

Comment: Glad to have helped.

Answer (score 2):

As Shubham has explained, the `/(user/settings)/:param1` path is matching `/user/:param1`. What you can do is to add the `exact` props, which sets it to true.

```
<Route exact path='/user/:param1'   component={routeProps => <MyTab {...routeProps} remotes={remotes} />}/>
<Route exact path='/(user/settings)/:param1'   component={UserSettings}/>
```

This disables the partial matching for the route, ensuring that it returns the route if the path exactly matches.

Comment: This will lead to issues if UserSettings or MyTab have nested routes